# How do I make a function that increases the column by 1 every time a button is pressed in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I'm working on a project in python, and I want to make a button that shifts the AddButton to the next column and puts a Network in its place.

My code below:

```
class NetAppHomePG:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 1

        self.AddImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("c:/Users/Will/Desktop/VSC_Test/NetworkApp/plus.png"))
        self.AddButton = Button(self.TabsFrame, image=self.AddImg, command=self.Add_Network).grid(row=0, ,column=1, padx=250, pady=0)

        self.NavBarFrame.grid(sticky=W)
        self.TabsFrame.grid(sticky=W)
       
        self.win.mainloop()

    def Add_Network(self):
        self.x =+ 1
        self.y =+ 1
        self.Network = Canvas(self.TabsFrame, width=400, height=600, background="grey")
        self.Network = Label(self.TabsFrame, text="Network #1", font=("Roboto", 18), foreground="lightblue", background="grey")
        self.Network.grid(row=0, column=(self.x), padx=250, pady=0)
        self.AddButton.grid(row=0, column=(self.y), padx=250, pady=0)
```

I tried assigning the AddButtons column to another variable and then incrementing the variable by one every time the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting up the grid inside `tabsFrame` with `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure`, and clear the button with `grid_forget` before replacing it with another call to `grid`

```
class NetAppHomePG:
    def __init__(self):
    ...  # code omitted for brevity
    self.TabsFrame.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    self.TabsFrame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    
    def Add_Network(self):
        self.x =+ 1
        self.y =+ 1
        self.Network = Canvas(self.TabsFrame, width=400, height=600, background="grey")
        self.Network = Label(self.TabsFrame, text="Network #1", font=("Roboto", 18), foreground="lightblue", background="grey")
        self.Network.grid(row=0, column=(self.x), padx=250, pady=0)
        
        self.AddButton.grid_forget()  # clear the button before replacing it below
        self.AddButton.grid(row=0, column=(self.y), padx=250, pady=0)
```

Comment: Appreciate the response, thanks

Comment: Sure thing - let me know if this works out for you.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please mark this answer as 'Accepted' so that others know this question has been answered.